# Qual a diferença entre M.dot, layout responsivo e layout adaptativo?

Tags: layout-responsivo

Sempre quando pesquisamos por desenvolvimento web responsivo encontramos diversas formas de fazer a *mesma coisa*.

Acessando o site do SOpt mesmo, podemos ver que ele possui um layout diferente para dispositivos mobiles e desktops, conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos ver que o tipo de layout do SOpt não é apenas responsivo, pois se você acessar o site em um desktop, alterar a resolução da tela mas não atualizar a mesma, a alteração de layout não ocorre.

Com essa dúvida em mente, realizei algumas pesquisas e três "termos" se destacam,  que são:

- Layout Responsivo
- Layout Adaptativo
- M.dot (este veio [desta conversa no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43454416#43454416))

Mas afinal, o que são esses "termos" e quais as diferenças entre eles?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Responsivo (responsive)

Estes podem fazer uso ou não de *media-queries*, o que define ele é que os tamanhos dos objetos acompanham a tela, geralmente baseado em porcentagem, então ele se ajusta conforme a necessidade não tendo um tamanho definido para cada elemento

### Adaptativo (adaptive)

Fazem uso de *media-queries* geralmente (ou talvez outros métodos de detecção), o que define este tipo é que ele trabalha com tamanhos fixos e se ajusta a medidas especificas.

Por exemplo se a tela estiver com o tamanho igual a 1024 o elemento principal da página (aonde se organiza os demais elementos) teria fixado o valor de `with: 1000px`, se a janela for redimensionada para 320 de largura um media-query vai adaptar aplicando a este elemento o tamanho fixo de `width: 300px;`, então o CSS seria algo como:

```css
.main {
     width: 1000px;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .main {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Este processo também pode ser aplicado em outros elementos, como por exemplo menus, então se acessar em um celular o menu pode ser totalmente modificado e terá um tamanho fixo para aquela necessidade.

### Comparando responsivo com adaptativo

Segue um exemplo bem simples das diferenças:

```html
<style>
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

#design {
    margin: 10px;
}
#design > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
}
.simulate {
     width: 320px;
}
#adaptive {
    width: 1000px;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
    #adaptive {
        width: 520px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    #adaptive {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
</style>

<div id="design">
    <div id="responsive">Responsive</div>
    <div id="adaptive">Adaptive</div>
</div>
```

Segue teste no jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ta9r0qza/2/, basta redimensionar o iframe para notar a diferença.

### Qual escolher, responsivo ou adaptativo?

Não vou falar de curva de aprendizagem e/ou grau de dificuldade, eu pessoalmente acho que isso é caso a caso, não tem como dizer qual é o melhor, se olharmos para muitos códigos fontes de sites que usam técnicas responsivas notará que também usam adaptativo em algum lugar, por exemplo um menu que é responsivo em todas telas de tamanho médio ou grandes, mas que em telas pequenas é fixado em um lugar da página e talvez seja ocultado e também terá o seu tamanho fixado para evitar ficar menor que o ideal.

Em resumo, ambas técnicas podem funcionar juntas para diferentes necessidades ou até combinadas.

---

### Outras técnicas

Durante as pesquisas encontrei as seguintes técnicas:

- `M.dot` (ou `Mdot` ou `M.`) que se refere a criar uma subdominio que entrega uma versão mobile da página
- Browser sniffing, que também é conhecido como:

  - browser detection
  - user-agent sniffing
  - user-agent detection
  - server-side sniffing
  - device detection

---

### Domínios e páginas alternativas para diferentes dispositivos

O `M.dot` é simplesmente um domínio alternativo, ainda sim ele pode fazer o uso do *browser sniffing* para que faça o redirecionamento HTTP (302 Found), ou seja se o usuário acessar o site Desktop em um celular ele será redirecionado para o subdomínio, como `m.site.com`.

Existem alternativa ao `M.dot` sem usar subdomínio, isso depende muito do que o desenvolvedor tem em mão, tem desenvolvedores que usam o PATH da URL, assim:

```
http://site.com/pagina.html
http://site.com/m/pagina.html
```

Querystring (é sério eu já vi isso):

```
http://site.com/pagina.html
http://site.com/pagina.html?mobile
```

Ou até mesmo domínios totalmente diferentes.

---

### Browser sniffing

Para entender esta técnica é necessário entender o header `User-Agent`, este header é enviado para o site que você esta tentando acessar em todas requisições HTTP, por exemplo se tentar abrir de um iPad a página `http://site/foo-bar-baz` será enviado ao servidor isto:

```
GET /foobar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
```

Então no lado do servidor é usando uma expressão para detectar a palavra `iPad` (e `Android`) no meio da string (podendo usar `regex` por exemplo), então se fosse em PHP seria algo como:

```php
if (preg_match('#\b(iPad|Android)\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    //Entrega conteúdo otimizado para mobile
} else {
    //Entrega conteúdo para Desktop
}
```

Ou redireciona:

```php
if (preg_match('#\b(iPad|Android)\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header('Location: http://m.site.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;//Impede de carregar o resto da página
}

//Entrega conteúdo para Desktop
```

Esta técnica no entanto é usada muito antes dos mobiles, na época que navegadores como IE4/5.01 e Netscape dominavam o mercado muita coisa não era compatível, então o uso de `user-agent` para detectar o navegador era bastante comum, seja para redirecionar para uma página otimizada para o navegador especifico ou até mesmo para bloquear o acesso naquele navegador (acredite as pessoas infelizmente faziam isto e as vezes ainda fazem).

Comment: Ótima resposta, votaria mais vezes se fosse possível!

Comment: Só tenho uma dúvida. Quando vc fala de `M.dot` você comenta sobre **subdomínios** ou **PATH** na URL. Porém, caso eu opte por ter 2 (ou mais)`views` diferentes para cada caso, isso se encaixaria em `M.dot`?

Comment: @Randrade ao meu ver M.dot é somente subdominio, que faz ou não uso do Browser sniffing, no caso acho que preciso revisar isto na resposta, mas são tecnicas bem semelhantes, não encontrei um termo comum entre elas.

Comment: @Randrade revisei a resposta, o texto ficou: > Existem alternativa ao M.dot sem usar sub-domínio, isso depende muito do que o desenvolvedor tem em mão, tem desenvolvedores que usam o PATH da URL ...

Comment: Alternativa? Teria um novo nome para isso?

Comment: @Randrade é o que prentendo buscar, mas creio que não exista, já que a coisa é muito variante